# Can any one help me in regular expression to allow only numbers and numbers range should be from 0.1 to 9999.99?

Tags: asp.net

Can any one help me in regular expression  to allow only numbers and numbers range should be from  0.1 to 9999.99?
Only 2 decimals are allowed.

I have tried it with this expression

```
^([1-9]\d{,3}(\.\d{1,2})?)?|(0\.([1-9]\d?)|(0\.0[1-9]))$
```

But not working.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: @JonathonReinhart-I have tried it with this expression ^([1-9]\d{,3}(\.\d{1,2})?)?|(0\.([1-9]\d?)|(0\.0[1-9]))$

Comment: If you have additional information (like that), don't post it in a comment. Instead, edit the original question to include the updated information.

Comment: Thanks for suggession, I have edited question.

Comment: Now doesn't this make you consider learning to use the tools available to you?

Comment: in asp.net, doesnt parseFloat() convert string to float, and return an error upon failure, so wouldnt that be easier than a home-brewed method? im just assuming thats whats going on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this regexp should meet your needs. Notice that the first term in the outermost group explicitly defines the minimum and the second term defines the maximum.

**Regexp**

```
^(?:(?:0{1,4}\.1\d?)|(?:\d{0,3}[1-9](?:\.[1-9]\d?)?))$
```

**Tests**

```
9999.99 -> success
2324 -> success
3241 -> success
0 -> failure
0.1 -> success
0.04 -> failure
9999.10 -> success
0.12 -> success
```

Comment: its is working for 105.66 but not for 100.66,10,0.25.pls help.